# Swift - CoreData: Retrieving Attributes from a Joined Table

Tags: swift, core-data

I was working on a Swift project trying to retrieve attribute data from a joined table.

To be specific, I have an entity called "Recipe" and one called "Ingredients". These 2 entities are many-to-many relationship with one another, meaning that, one recipe can include many ingredients, and one ingredient can belong to many recipes. An intermediate table "RecipeIngredient" is also built to facilitate the connection.

What I am trying to do now is to retrieve attributes' value from "Recipe" and those from "Ingredients" which are joined with "Recipe", and display them to some UI labels. What should I do in order to get attributes from "Ingredients", and what commands should I use in the code?

Any help or guidance is appreciated !! Let me know if I need more elaboration on my question (:

PS: I've attached some screenshots about what I am trying to do. Hope that would provide with some contexts.

[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juClF.png)

[Codes to retrieve attributes' value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXPIY.png)

Comment: has_ingred is `NSSet` of RecipieIngradient, you need to process it before assigning it to `text`.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore sorry I am quite new to CoreData...I understand it is different from SQL databases but it's hard for me to visualise the concept. Could you elaborate your answer with some codes?

Comment: Don't post images of code, include the code as text instead.

Comment: You don't use mapping tables in core data, instead you create to-many relationships in both directions between Recipe and Ingredients

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Please don't distract both of us into something unnecessary and irrelevant.

Comment: @davehyy, maybe you should read the documentation

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Maybe you should at least look at my question and attempt to think on it?

Comment: I gave you an advice but you regarded it irrelevant